# IF condition is not satisfied, return on the beginning and don't do anything

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a pretty big code so I wont put it here... 
I made some calculation which works and now I want to repair certain things.

I created for loop with statement: if (my condition) is true break and
 save, else if (condition is not true) show message box and report what
 is wrong (like example input is 0 and should not be 0). But after that
 my calculation goes on till the end and dont stop there. How to stop
 it there until my condition is not satisfied?

What to add with return??  I have it in private void function on
 button click.. This bothers me becouse in my program there is lots of
 if conditions with show/hide options. So when program continue with
 calculation it show lots of 0 and bad numbers..

**I am calling this function (radio button checked) with another one (button click)
The input inside if statement is from textboxes converted to numbers**

```
if (Math.Abs(miSdCrtica - _dMiSd) < 0.01)
{
    epsilonS1 = epsilonS1Pretpostavka;
    zeta = zetaRacunska;
    ksi = ksiRacunski;
    xNeutralnaOs = ksi * _dd;
    zKrakSila = zeta * _dd;
    racunskiAs1 = (_dMed * 1000) / (zeta * _dd * dFyd);
    break;
}
else if (_dMiSd < 0.086)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error - check input");
    return;
}
```

**And after this Error - check input thing, code continues and give me bunch of zero's (0)**

I hope this helped to clear up some things

***Problem demo***

**I have some texboxes for UI, radio button to choose from 2 conditions and button for calculation**

radiobutton

```
private void combobox_indexChanged ()
  if statement (radiobutton checked)
     for loop (written above)
       if statement (written above)
       else if statement (written above)
```

button click

```
private void button clicked()
   calls radiobutton checked (do calculation)
       hide/show bunch of labels  (their results are 0 with  else if statement from above)
```

how to stop it so when `MessageBox.Show("Error - check input");`  is shown, the button click function does not continue to hide/show labels but to stop until UI is right?

I hope now is clear what i want to do

Comment: Have a look at the `while` keyword.

Comment: If you try to add some code that demonstrates the specific scenario, then you will probably get better help.   Things like "goes on till the end and dont stop there" can be interpreted a dozen different ways.

Comment: Even if the code is incomplete/non-working, you can add a comment `// here I want it to jump to the end of the function instead of continuing` to express your desire

Comment: the code is too big to put it here... i am noob programmer
I will try get something out...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I strongly suspect `while` is not going to help as it sounds values coming from UI elements - so basic `while` will just freeze UI thread... Some fancy threaded code that pulls updates from UI all the time may work, but it is unlikely solution to OP's problem.

Comment: You should listen to AaronLS. Code is needed. It's the easiest way for people to know exactly what you're talking about. If the code is too big, post what's relevant or at least what you think is relevant.

Comment: @antestipe - There is no expirience/age restrictions on http://www.sscce.org/ site... Check it out before adding sample.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I suspect you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, I suppose your button click event looks something like:

```
void Button1_Click(...){
    if(radioButton1.Checked){
        RadioButton1Checked();
    }
    if(radioButton2.Checked){
        SomeOtherFunction();
    }
    ...
}

void RadioButton1Checked(){
    for(...){
        //code from the question
    }
}
```

You don't want the other code to run if code in RadioButton1Checked "failed". So you could change that function to return `bool`.

```
bool RadioButton1Checked(){
    for(...){
        if (Math.Abs(miSdCrtica - _dMiSd) < 0.01)
        {
           //...
            racunskiAs1 = (_dMed * 1000) / (zeta * _dd * dFyd);
            break;
        }
        else if (_dMiSd < 0.086)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void Button1_Click(...){
    if(radioButton1.Checked){
        if(!RadioButton1Checked()){ //if the function returns false
            //Display message box
            return;
        }
    }
    if(radioButton2.Checked){
        if(!SomeOtherFunction()){
            //Display message box
            return;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could throw an ArgumentException from your function and catch it.

```
else if (_dMiSd < 0.086)
{
    //I suggest you to specify which input exactly is faulty
    throw new ArgumentException("Error - check input");
}

void Button1_Click(...){
    try{
        if(radioButton1.Checked){
            RadioButton1Checked();
        }
        if(radioButton2.Checked){
            SomeOtherFunction();
        }
        ...
    }catch(ArgumentException e){
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

A general suggestion is that you make all your calculation functions parametric. A function should take a set of parameters and calculate a result based on those parameters only (without variables declared outside the function scope - i.e class members or global variables).

I suppose you have something like:

```
class ...{
   double epsilonS1;
   double zeta;

   void Button_Click(..){
       double.Parse(textBoxEpsilon.Text, out epsilonSi);
       zeta = 0.02;
       Calculate();
   }

   void Calculate(){
       epsilonS1 = epstilonS1 * zeta * 0.01f;
   }
```

}

Problem with this is if your calculation process needs to fail - then you had already changed a lot of your 'global' variables, and it's not easy to return to the previous state (before you called the function).

Instead of that, try to make your functions like so:

```
class ...{
   void Button_Click(..){
       double epsilon = 0;
       double.Parse(textBoxEpsilon.Text, out epsilon);
       double result = Calculate(epsilon, zeta);
   }

   //function takes parameters, and returns a result.
   //It neither reads nor changes variables that are outside its scope
   double Calculate(double epsilonS1, double zeta){
       return epsilonS1 * zeta * 0.01f;
   }
```

}

If function written like this fails, you can be sure that it didn't change any global variables, so the program 'state' is the same as it was before the function was called.

Yes, it's a long answer, a lot needed to be said (and assumed since I didn't actually see your code).

---

P.S.

`RadioButton.Checked` values are good parameters for a function (those that are relevant to the calculation - those that are only used to indicate whether UI should display a value or not should be left outside). Instead of calling (what I assume you are doing) a lot of individual functions based on checkbox values, you could just pass those values to the function and make calculations (or call other functions) based on them.

```
void Calculate(double epsilon, double zeta, bool calculatePhi, bool showZulu){
    epsilon = zeta * 0.01;
    if(calculatePhi){
        phi = epsilon / 2;
        if(phi < 0.1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input - epsilon");
    } 
}
```

If you need to return multiple values from a function, a simple way to do that is to create a class that will contain those values, then return an instance of that class.

```
class Result{
    public double Epsilon {get; set;}
    public double Zeta {get;set;}
    ...
    public bool DisplayZeta {get;set;}
}
```

And your calculate function could look like:

```
Result Calculate(double epsilon, double zeta, bool calculatePhi, bool showZulu){
    Result result = new Result();
    result.Epsilon = zeta * 0.01;
    if(showZulu){
       result.DisplayZeta = true;
    } 

    return Result;
}
```

By the way, when you need to do calculations, don't put them in the event handlers, make specialized functions (methods) that perform them. Instead of doing your calculation in the RadioButton_Checked(...) event, do it in Calculate() method, which you can call from the event handler and the button click.

Comment: 1st block of code is good only problem what I forgot to mention is that it is private void comboBox_indexchanged and in that is if statement (radiobutton changed) -->
private void radiobutton is defined outside and called in comboBox because it take data from comboBox and use them...

in 3rd block of code the faulty value cant be specified because _dMiSd is calculated value...

Since i am a begginer i think i will need to rewrite my code in a better way and i will use your suggestions. Thanks allot for effort...

Veliki pozdrav :)

Comment: When the input is faulty, it's better to give the user a hint as to what might be wrong (maybe list multiple fields?). Pozdrav! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use "return;" to exit out of the void method wherever you want to stop the execution.

Comment: when i put return on the end it only stops my current execution, but other one continue... i want to stop it and return on the begining of the "stoped" one

Comment: Not sure if i get it right when you say the "other one continues". Can you provide some snippet so can i tell you precisely what you can do.

Comment: i will edit my question with some simple example of the problem...

Comment: Okie you want to return from button click when there is an error in radio button checked. You have to notify the button click that there is an error. You should create a seperate method that returns a bool and put the logic inside the radiobutton and return false in case of an error. In button click check for if this method returns false and then exit.

Comment: hmm... must figure out how to do that because i have some nested if statements inside this radio button checked method which does not apply for this error

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you throw a breakpoint on the line `break;`? It might help to see what's going on with your numbers, and also to make sure you are passing in the right values.

When Visual Studio stops at the breakpoint, mouse over all of your variables in your code and make sure they make sense.

If you find something that doesn't look right, you're one step closer to identifying the problem.

Comment: everything is ok with break it just go to another function.. becouse when error is thrown i need to be returned on user input but instead of that, the calculation continues, only this void method stops but the other one (which is real calculation on button click) goes on and give me zero's...

Comment: Then you need to tell whatever function that is to stop. Like XtremeBytes said, if a condition is met where a method needs to stop, use `return;`. It's up to you to figure out what that condition is.